# Brightness control on Awesome windowing manager

Tags: brightness, awesome

I have just installed Awesome WM and I have no options to change the screen brightness, and also its shortcut doesn't working. Any one can help?

Comment: You can try xbacklight.

Answer (score 21):

In the `globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(` section of `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`:

```
    -- Brightness

    awful.key({ }, "XF86MonBrightnessDown", function ()
        awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -dec 15") end),
    awful.key({ }, "XF86MonBrightnessUp", function ()
        awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -inc 15") end),
```

Comment: ...in the `globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(` section, more precisely.

Answer (score 11):

1) Install xbacklight:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

2) Test it in console:

```
xbacklight -inc 10
xbacklight -dec 10
```

3) Add hotkeys to your awesome config ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua

Insert inside [globalkeys = awful.util.table.join] section the following text:

```
awful.key({ }, "XF86MonBrightnessDown", function ()
    awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -dec 15") end),
awful.key({ }, "XF86MonBrightnessUp", function ()
    awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -inc 15") end)
```

I use a keyboard without XF86MonBrightness* that's why I added bindings to Mod+o, Mod+p:

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "p", function ()                           
    awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -dec 15") end),                            
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "o", function ()                           
    awful.util.spawn("xbacklight -inc 15") end)
```

Hope this helps )

Comment: This worked for me. Although the response is really slow. I have about 2-5 seconds between pressing the button and the screen actually changing. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: If xbacklight is not working for you, try [these suggestions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#ACPI), in particular `/sys/class/backlight`.

Answer (score 6):

I autostart `xfce4-power-manager`, which will let you adjust the brightness using the brightness keys, in addition to general power management, such as suspend/resume, battery notifications, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to load "gnome-power-manager" inside awesome, or at awesome startup:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome#Transitioning_away_from_Gnome3
Hope this helps

Another option is to run awesome inside gnome, then you can just rely on the gnome controls (working fine) and networking etc is working too
http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome

Answer (score 1):

To make an app autostart when you login in Awesome WM:
**Right click on Desktop go to awesome > edit config**.
append the following line at the end:

```
-- Autorun programs in Awesome WM
autorun = true
autorunApps =
{
   "xfce4-power-manager",

}
if autorun then
   for app = 1, #autorunApps do
       awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app])
   end
end
```

Replace "xfce4-power-manager" with your power manager.

Comment: On systems with no DEs, is `xfce4-power-manager` a good choice for getting a laptop's brightness buttons working? Or, is there something even more minimal? I like your handle, btw (funny).